# Как передать значение одного столбца в столбец другой таблицы MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

Есть tab1, столбец id инкремируемый:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, user VARCHAR(2
00) NOT NULL, age int(7) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));

id, user, age
 1,  A  ,   12
```

И tab2:

```
CREATE TABLE tab2(id_1 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, id_meta int(7) NOT NULL, height int(7) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id_1), FOREIGN KEY (id_meta)  REFERENCES tab1 (id));

id_1, id_meta, height
14,   1,      180
```

Импортирую с помощью Python данные в tab1:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO tab1(user, age) VALUES ("A", 12)
```

Как можно импортировать в tab2 в столбец `height` значение 180, чтобы значение в столбце `id_meta` соответствовало `id` из `tab1` ?

Comment: Покажите структуру таблиц в виде их полных CREATE TABLE.

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: Структура не обеспечивает уникальности вставляемой совокупности полей `tab1 (user, age)`. Задача нерешаема.

Comment: Как это понять?

Comment: А очень просто. Вот ты делаешь `INSERT INTO tab1(user, age) VALUES ("A", 12)`. А потом повторяешь. У тебя две записи, различающиеся только значением `id`. На какую ссылаться - неизвестно.

Comment: у менять есть данные допустим в .csv A;12;180, вот мне нужно раскидать их во время импорта по двум таблица, в одну таблицу А и 12 в другую 180, они должны быть связаны по айди